# Generate Empty xml root node in SQL even if there are no records

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008

I have a problem with generating empty\null xml root node from sql. This is an exmaple of the structure that I'm working on:

```
<Departments>
    <Department>
        <Employees>
         <Employee>
            <Name></Name>
            <ID></ID>
         </Employee>
        </Employees>
    </Department>
    </Departments>
```

Below is the sql that I use to generate the structure :

```
declare @Employee table (Name varchar(50), ID int, DID int)
declare @Department table (Name varchar(50), DID int)
declare @xmldata xml

insert into @Employee values ('AAA', 1, 3)
insert into @Employee values ('BBB', 2, 3)
--insert into @Department values ('CCC', 3)

SET @xmldata = 
(

select GETDATE() as 'ReportDate', (

select D.Name,
(
select (
       select E.Name,
              E.ID
       from @Employee E
    where E.DID = D.DID
       for xml path ('Employee'), elements xsinil, type    
       )
for xml path('Employees'), type
)
from @Department D
for xml path('Department'), type
)

for xml path ('Departments'), type
)
select @xmldata
```

If there are records, the xml structure is coming properly but my problem is if there are no department record, there is no  node at all. How do I show at least the  empty node in the xml?

If no department record, xml will be :

```
<Departments>
  <ReportDate>2016-08-11T16:31:22.960</ReportDate>
</Departments>
```

What I like to have is :

```
<Departments>
  <ReportDate>2016-08-11T16:31:22.960</ReportDate>
  <Department />
</Departments>
```

Comment: so there is actually record but with empty name and empty ID and actual version is ommiting it ?

Comment: If there are employees record, it is fine as the whole structure is coming in xml. The problem is when there are no employees record and xml is not even showing <Employees />.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a derived table with 1 row and do an outer apply to a query against `@Departments`.

```sql
select getdate() as ReportDate,
       (
       select D.Name,
              isnull(D.Employees, '') as Employees
       from (select null) as T(N)
         outer apply (
                     select D.Name,
                            (
                            select E.Name,
                                   E.ID
                            from @Employee E
                            where E.DID = D.DID
                            for xml path ('Employee'), elements xsinil, type    
                            ) as Employees
                     from @Department as D
                     ) as D
       for xml path('Departments'), type
       )
for xml path('Departments'), type
```

Answer (score 0):

I got to know about your issue. You may try below concept.

```
SELECT ISNULL(s.lmx, '<Users></Users>')
FROM 
    (
        select 1 as tag, null as parent,
        FirstName as [User!1!FirstName!Element],
        LastName as [User!1!LastName!Element]
        FROM Users
        FOR XML EXPLICIT
    ) AS s(lmx)
```

I too faced the same problem and I got the hint from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15503798/sql-server-2008-xml-empty-node)

Comment: I came across this as well. Just wonder if there is a more elegant way of doing this.